# windows batch script: nested for loops not working

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I am writing a windows batch script which uses robocopy to backup files. I want to mimic the behaviour of linux rsync, which by default adds the top level source directory to the destination path. I am not aware that robocopy can do this as it copies only the subdirectories of the source to the destination. Therefore I am using the following script to extract the top level directory from the path to add it to the destination path using two nested for loops.

I simplified the script below to focus on the part which is not working.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set source[0]=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys
set source[1]=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\Custom Office Templates

set dest=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test

:: range in for loop specified as (start,step,end)
for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
  for %%a in ("!source[%%x]!") do (
    set ddir=%%~nxa
  )
  echo "!source[%%x]!" "%dest%\%ddir%"
)
```

The script produces the following output:

```
"C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys" "C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test\"
"C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\Custom Office Templates" "C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test\"
```

The %ddir% variable is empty. Therefore the top level directory of the source path is not added to the destination as I intend. I would like to achieve the following output:

```
"C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys" "C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test\keys"
"C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\Custom Office Templates" "C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test\Custom Office Templates"
```

I tested the outer and inner for loops separately and then the partial scripts work as expected. Of course the inner for loop cannot access the whole source array in this case.

Outer for loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set source[0]=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys
set source[1]=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\Custom Office Templates

:: range in for loop specified as (start,step,end)
for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
  echo "!source[%%x]!"
)
```

Output:

```
"C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys"
"C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\Custom Office Templates"
```

Inner for loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set source[0]=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys
set dest=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test

for %%a in ("!source[0]!") do (
  set ddir=%%~nxa
)
```

Output:

```
"C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys" "C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test\keys"
```

Any ideas what is wrong with the nested for loops?

Comment: You need to use delayed expansion also for variable `ddir` in the `echo` command line...

Comment: `The %ddir% variable is empty.` because you need to use `!ddir!` with enabledelayedexpansion.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. I think I haven't really understood the "delayedexpansion" concept of windows scripting yet ...

Comment: In the beginning variables were expanded when the line is read (brackets make many lines into one). Many scripts depend on this original behaviour. When IBM's engineers (OS/2 where CMD came from was a joint MS/IBM project) enhanced the command prompt they made runtime expansion possible (that is when the variable is used). To maintain compatibility with existing scripts you have to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delayed expansion of variables and path arguments expansion correctly. Try this and let me know any issues:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set "source[0]=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\keys"
set "source[1]=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\Custom Office Templates"
set "dest=C:\Users\Sample User\Documents\test"

:: range in for loop specified as (start,step,end)
for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
  for /f %%a in ("!source[%%x]!") do (
    set "ddir=%%~na" & set "dst=%dest%\!ddir!"
    echo "!source[%%x]!" "!dst!" ))
exit /b
```

Comment: @Pohl7534 If the script works for you, consider upvoting AND accepting any answer in this thread by clicking "Arrow Up" and "Select" signs to the left of the answer. :)

Comment: Your suggestion works if I remove the `/f` switch from the inner for loop. As  @TessellatingHeckle already pointed out, all which needed changing in the original script was using delayedexpansion for the `!ddir!` variable.

Comment: Comments don't allow proper Google search. To find answers, they must be posted as answers, not comments.